# Unable to pull image with Docker client for Go

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to pull a Docker image with the Go client. This is my code:

```
imageId := "x.x.x.x:5000/myimage:latest" //with an actual IP, ofc
r, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageId, types.ImagePullOptions{
  Platform: "linux/amd64",
})
if err != nil {
  return err
}
defer r.Close()
```

As you can see, I'm pulling it from my own registry. I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: No such image:
> x.x.x.x:5000/myimage:latest

However, if I pull the image using Docker CLI, it works like a charm:

```
$ docker pull x.x.x.x:5000/myimage:latest
```

Note: My Docker registry is an insecure one. So, in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, I have this:

```
{ "insecure-registries": ["x.x.x.x:5000"] }
```

Note 2: In my Dockerfile, I'm using the `--platform` flag:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node
// ...
```

Comment: Do you see anything useful in the logs from your registry server?

Comment: Are you logged in on the CLI using. eg. a credential helper?

Comment: I don't see any error in the registry logs. I have edited the question. Please, check it.